# How can I change my color mixer back to the default Adobe version?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs6

I was changing the color settings in my Photoshop CS6 the other day; now I get the Windows color mixer (below) instead of the Adobe color mixer.

[image: this is the windows color picker/mixer and is not what I want.].

... so my dilemma is I cannot remember exactly everything I did. I was working off of multiple sites to help make my colors the same as the print as on the screen. But this Windows color mixer is very impractical; it doesn't show the color number or anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can change that setting by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> that will bring the "Preferences":

[image: Change Color Mixer]

Just select the Color Picker named "Adobe".